# Yii2 webapp on Azure not working

Tags: php, azure, yii, yii2

I am having a website + services app built on Yii + Yii2 framework respectively.
I tried hosting it on Azure http://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/ . website which was built on Yii1 was working fine. Services built on Yii2 endpoint returning 404. the services are working in local.

Here are the details:

```
Local: Xampp server
htdocs/
       myapp/
             dashboard/            ---> this the website folder (Yii)
             modules/
                     v1/           -----> here are my yii2 services and controllers.
```

Now when I try locally with url: http://localhost/myapp/v1/srvc/srvdetails
is working fine.

When I try Azure URL i.e. http://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/v1/srvc/srvdetails not working.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: its returning 404, mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According your description, it seems that you have a `.htaccess` file in your application to hidden `index.php` pattern in URL. As the PHP scripts are handled by IIS on Azure Web Apps, so you can try to generate a `web.config` file with following content to instead your `.htaccess`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>

<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />

  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Hide Yii Index" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" 
              ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" 
              ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule> 
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Otherwise, you can provide your complete application structure for us for further diagnosis. Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks Gary. it worked. got a new issue. now the request is reaching and getting error msg: 500. when i tried in xampp local with a remote db its working fine. when trying from azure portal or iis its returning: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. any idea?

Comment: Yes I'd love to help you, but as this issue is little relationship with your original question, and I suggest you to create a new question on SO with your detailed error message and essential info, like what database server you are using, and the configurations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gary, here is the question with necessary details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584609/azurewebsites-iis-7-internal-server-when-connecting-to-remote-mysql-db-using-yii