# azurewebsites/IIS 7 internal server when connecting to remote MySQL db using Yii 2 framework

Tags: mysql, azure, iis, yii2, cleardb

I have a Azure WebApp + Services written in **Yii and Yii 2** respectively.
The database is **MySQL db from ClearDB**. i am hosting it on using the **empty Php app**.

> Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/07/23/migrate-yii-framework-application-to-azure-web-app/

The webapp is working fine. In services when trying to connect to the ClearDB MySQL its working fine in XAMPP.

When use the same code in IIS 7 in my local (to simulate azurewebsites) i am receiving: i am getting error **500 (Internal server error)** with message: **SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]** No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. When i placed the same code on azurewebsites: i am getting error 500 (Internal server error) with no message,

Here is my project structure:

```
 Local: Xampp server
 htdocs/
       myapp/
             dashboard/            ---> this the website folder (Yii)
             modules/
                     v1/           -----> here are my yii2 services and controllers.
```

Comment: I tried `Yii::$app->db->open();` both on Azure and IIS on local to test the connection but couldn't reproduce your issue. Could you connect to database via mysql workbench successfully? And you can follow https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations to show error message on Azure

Comment: I am able to connect from woekbench. here is the error message from dump taken from Kudu. Detailed Error Information:
"" Module    FastCgiModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    PHP56_via_FastCGI
Error Code    0x00000000
Requested URL    http://testleads:80/index.php
Physical Path    D:\home\site\wwwroot\index.php
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User    Anonymous""

Comment: i have checked in my windows xampp, getting the same error as in iis: "status_code": 500,
  "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\r\n"
magically its working in mac + xampp. need to change some settings in windows? any idea?

Comment: Maybe you can try to separate your applications in yii1 & yii2 into two independent applications in two independent Azure Web Apps.

Comment: two webapps worked Gary. Thanks for the suggestion. anyway to make it a single app? it will help me in cost reduction.

Comment: Have you tried to close db connection each time when you query someting whether in yii1 or yii2.

Comment: yes. closing the connection is in place in both the apps