# How to propper configure web.config on IIS to publish YII2 Advanced

Tags: yii2, iis-7, web-config, yii2-advanced-app

I am installing a YII2 advanced theme based app. It runs beautifully on Apache, but the pretty urls just breake horribly when installing on IIS 7, I am using the following web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
            <sectionGroup name="rewrite">
                <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
                <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But this one just will not work, because when opening a specific route, it tries to go to that route and not to build the proper route inside YII2.

This problem can be seen on the error that is being thrown, you can see that it's trying to open the physical path \web\user\login, that obviously does not exist. when instead it should open something like `.../index.php?r=controller/action`

[image]

On apache I would use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Any idea that can help me fixing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 webapp on Azure not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40551901/yii2-webapp-on-azure-not-working)

Comment: @lex-li close, the answer could indicate that its a duplicate. I am not sure. But still, the answer they have there doesn't answer the question here. How to make a correcto configuration on the web.config? Still fighting with it.
The answer confuses me a little they are pointing to another question that refers to the database.

Comment: This question I guess is very clear, the referred duplicate is not. The problem here is how to get the web.config configured so it will route the controller/action to point inside the index.php?r=
Please @lex-li let me know if you think I am wrong, and what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of searching and trying to understand why dos does not work. Ind not having much luck.

Finally I found.

**FIRST:**
Make sure you have installed URL Rewrite on your IIS7.

If you have the web.config configuration, and it is still routing to a physical directory and not to the controller/action route, it almost 100% means that your are missing `URL Rewrite`. Yes this is an addon that is not necessarily installed.

So go ahead, download and install it on your ISS from [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

[image]

**SECOND:**
This is the web.config that is actually working. Notice that I ended with: `match url=".*"` and also notice that I added a line to handle images and other static content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
            <sectionGroup name="rewrite">
                <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
                <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Yii2 Routing that works" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions  logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html" negate="true" />                            
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**AND FINALLY** 
If your are using the YII2 advanced theme, be sure to update and configure your web.config in both web directories.

This menas, you will need to have them on:
C:\webroot****\www\backend\web\web.config
C:\webroot****\www\frontend\web\web.config

And be sure to have your main.php «or config.php on basic» updated
on advanced you will need to be sure that your enablePrtettyUrl its configured for frontend and backend:

C:\webroot****\www\backend\config\main.php
C:\webroot****\www\frontend\config\main.php

```
'urlManager' => [
   'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
   'showScriptName' => false,
...
]
```

I am still debugging and trying to solve some minor problems, os I will update if I find something else.